# What does что ~ что ... mean?

Tags: грамматика

In the following sentence:

> Французы различают стадии отношений, а в России как бы считается важным максимально быстро начать пользоваться такими называниями как "жена", "моя жена" или "муж", "мой муж". Франкоязычные люди имеют стадии отношений, через которые они проходят, и они не торопятся называть человека мужем или женой (**что на французском mon homme или ma femme, что я читаю, как мужчина или женщина в моей жизни**).

> Source: https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/16469883

I'm not sure what this что ~ что ... means. I could not find any explanations on this что ~ что... construction on my resources. At least I understand the meaning of the sentence (French don't call their partner as муж/жена as quickly as Russians do). So how does this construction work?

Comment: This example is IMHO incorrect and would be better served by other conjunctions like "что ~ то" or "то, что ~"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two separate conjunctions:

- **which** is 'mon homme' or 'ma femma' in French, **which** I read as the man or woman of my life.

P.S. The comma before **как** is not needed.

There is, however, the complex conjunction **что... что...** found, for example, in [что в лоб, что по лбу](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1,_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%83).

Comment: Thanks so are both что(s) here relative pronouns? Are they replaceable with который?

Comment: @Blaszard, yes, you could replace **что** with **который**: они не торопятся называть человека мужем или женой (которые на французском - mon homme или ma femme, которые я читаю как «мужчина или женщина в моей жизни»). **Который** refers to the specific word while **что** refers to the whole preceding clause.